# Add custom menu on FullPage.js section

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fullpage.js

I am using fullpage.js for my website.
I was wondering if I can add a non-sticky menu to all my sections,
I have tried just to put the menu code on all my website section, But it is make my website slowly. Someone have any ideas?

Comment: can you try using this [example](https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/fixedHeaders.html) and remove header from that, it don't have menu then also it works with page by page.

Comment: @Webinion But the menu on this example is a fixed menu, I need a non fixed menu. Thank you.

Comment: please make jsfiddle, so I can see code and make changes.

Comment: @Webinion Here is my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uz2brh8o/)

Answer (score 1):

So you want for each individual section to have its own menu?

In that case this might do
html:

```
<div id="fullpage">
  <div class="section">section 1</div>
  <div class="section">
    <div class="sectionMenue">This is the menue for section 2</div>
    section 2
  </div>
  <div class="section">
    <div class="sectionMenue">This is the menue for section 3</div>
    section 3
  </div>
<div class="section">section 4</div>
```

css:

```
.sectionMenue {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r7xehhyf/18/)

fullpage will modify all of the sections once it runs, making the positions of all the sections fixed. that means that any absolute positioning inside one of these sections will position it relative to the section itself. Hope that makes sense

Comment: I want the same menu on all the sections.  I  have abig menu, and i tried jusy to put the big menu code in all the sections, but it makes my website slow. There is another option to use the menu on all the sections without calling the menu in all the sections?

Comment: No. I want non fixed menu